# Why doesn't my Bootstrap modal work in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal

Hi im trying to make a modal popup with bootstrap and WordPress.

Its working fine in my static HTML/CSS site, but when i try to put it into my wordpress theme, the modal popup seems not to be working.

I have enqueue bootstrap in my `functions.php` like this:

```
// Including stylesheets and script files
function load_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_style('template', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/template.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery', 'popper' ), '4.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstra-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.0.0', 'all' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

But it still seems like its not working.

I hope you can help - and please bear with me I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Is the question about loading scripts or your modal instance? Check the console and narrow down the actual problem. As it is I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: add your modal code part not this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo that might be why it's not working. In the last enqueue style link, bootstrap is missing the "p". So it says **bootstra** instead of bootstrap.